# polymer 2.0 two way binding

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I am experimenting with Polymer 2.0 and have a simple class.  It has an input text box that does not respond when changing its content. What is needed to reflect changes to text box to reflect as two way binding?

The code for the class follows.

```
<!-- Styles MUST be inside template -->
<style>
</style>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="greeting" name="greeting" value="{{greeting}}"/>
  <slot></slot>
  {{greeting}}
</div>
```

```
// Extend Polymer.Element base class
class Polymer2Class extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'polymer-2-class' }
  static get config() {
    return {
      properties: {
        greeting: {
          type: String,
          value: "Hello",
          notify: true
          //observer: 'greetingChanged'
        }
      },
      observers: [
        'greetingChanged(greeting)'
       ]
    }
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('created');
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    console.log('attached');
  }
  ready() {
    this.addEventListener('click', (e)=>this.handleClick(e));
    this._ensureAttribute('tabIndex', 0);
    super.ready();
    console.log('ready');
  }
  greetingChanged(greeting) {
    if(greeting === undefined) {
      console.log("greetingChanged: undefined");
    } else {
      console.log("greetingChanged: " + greeting);
    }
  }
  handleClick(e) {
    console.log("hamdleClick: " + e.type);
  }

// Register custom element definition using standard platform API
customElements.define(Polymer2Class.is, Polymer2Class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're expecting `greeting` to appear below the `<input>` exactly *as you type it*. You'll need to use [two-way native binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#two-way-native) on the `<input>`'s `input` event:

```
<input type="text" value="{{greeting::input}}">
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NbKwjX?editors=1010)

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning you can also write `{{greeting::keyup}}` instead of `{{greeting::input}}`. As the name implies the `greeting` scoped property will get updated when you release the key on an input.

Comment: The OP is asking about Polymer 2.0, but the linked doc is Polymer 1.0

Comment: @neverendingqs Updated for consistency. Note the relevant section in the 1.0 docs is identical to the 2.0 docs.